# How to find element with offset in nested lists?

Tags: list, algorithm, math, data-structures, nested

I'm currently work on an algorithmic problem in c# (Language doesn't matter).
I have 3 nested lists with that are **not the same length** (see the illustration below).

[image: Problem illustration]

```cs
// Elements can be anything. For example, here i used strings
List<List<List<string>>> elements = new()
{
    new() { new List<string>() { "E0", "E1" }, new List<string>() { "E2" } },
    new() { new List<string>() { "E3" }, new List<string>() { "E4", "E5" }, new List<string>() { "E6", "E7", "E8" } },
    new() { new List<string>() { "E9" } }
};
```

I know the i, j and k indexes for a given element (we can call it **E**) and I'm trying to find the indexes of another element (**F**) with an offset from E.

On this example, we are trying to find F indexes (1,2,1) by only knowing E indexes (0,1,0) and the offset (5 in this case).

I'm trying to find how to transform my 3 nested lists into a data structure that allows me to solve this problem easily.

Any help or idea are welcomed :)

I have tried to use if/else system but it was way to complicated. I also tried some Data Structures without any success.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you would provide some initialisation code for the data structure you have pictured. Nested lists can be implemented in multiple ways...

Comment: You need to know the maximum index values, imax, jmax(i), and kmax(i,j) then loop over them offset times starting from E.

Comment: [I would add the indexing information to each element in the tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcwG1.png).

Comment: @trincot Here a simple initialisation for that list in c# :
`List<List<List<Element>>> elements = new List<List<List<Element>>>();`
I fill the list afterwards .

Comment: Please edit your question, and add it there. And please add the code to build the example list.

Comment: @trincot Done ! Sry, i'm not really used to ask question on StackOverflow ^^'

Comment: @user3386109 That's an idea. Could work perfectly, i'm gonna try this and let you know if everything works well.

Comment: @SimonGoater I'm gonna try this as well, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decide to not change the data structure, you can still walk through the tree as follows:

```cpp
void walk(List<List<List<string>>> a, int[] indices, int distance) {
    while (indices[0] < a.Count) {
        List<List<string>> b = a[indices[0]];
        while (indices[1] < b.Count) {
            List<string> c = b[indices[1]];
            while (indices[2] < c.Count) {
                if (distance-- <= 0) return; // Found target
                indices[2]++;
            }
            indices[1]++;
            indices[2] = 0;
        }
        indices[0]++;
        indices[1] = 0;
    }
    // Out of range. Caller could check if `indices[0]` is within range
}
```

Example call:

```cpp
// Example input given in the question
List<List<List<string>>> elements = new()
{
    new() { new List<string>() { "E0", "E1" }, new List<string>() { "E2" } },
    new() { new List<string>() { "E3" }, new List<string>() { "E4", "E5" }, new List<string>() { "E6", "E7", "E8" } },
    new() { new List<string>() { "E9" } }
};
int[] indices = {0, 1, 0}; // Starting point
walk(elements, indices, 5); // Walk 5 steps
System.Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", indices));  // 1, 2, 1
```